# How to remove fieldset borders

Tags: javascript, extjs

This question was asked dozens of times, but with respect to previous versions of the `ExtJS` library. In `ExtJS 6` old receipts are not working. So, this is how my fieldset looks when I do not set `border` property to `false`:

[image]

And this is how it looks like when I do `border: false`:

[image]

As you can see, there still remains that nasty top border. It looks like a bug and so, I wonder, how to fix it.

Comment: Why use a fieldset if you don't want fieldset styling?

Comment: You have a point there. I just used to grouping a number of fields with a fieldset. But probably you are right and I should switch to something else.

Comment: Just use a container.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1eub), some crucial information seems to be missing from your post.

Comment: @Alexander. Just add `border: false` to the second `fieldset` and you are done :)